# JavaScript Naming with var name as elements from group

Tags: javascript, var

I want to make hundreds groups like this..

```
        var aa = [];
        var bb = [];
        .
        .
        .
```

I am tired of hardcoding, so I made group.
However when I declare var name, it is not easy.
Please help me some Javascript logic.

```
        var groups = ['aa', 'bb', ....];

        var groups.[0];
```

Comment: so, what exactly do you want?

Comment: *"I want to make hundreds groups like this.."* That almost certainly means you want to use an array or object, not discrete variables.

Comment: maybe, it is time for a better data structure.

Comment: You want an **object**: `var groups = { aa: [], bb: [], ... };`

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807231/how-to-dynamically-create-javascript-variables-from-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to make hundreds groups like this..

That almost certainly means you want to use an array or object, not discrete variables. It looks like you're already sort of headed that way.

If the names must be `aa`, `bb`, and so on, and the number of them is known in advance, you can add them to an object with a loop:

```js
var obj = {};
var n;
var ch;
for (n = 0; n < 26; ++n) {
    ch = String.fromCharCode(97 + n); // 97 = 'a'
    obj[ch + ch] = [];
}
console.log(obj);
```

...but with broader context we could probably propose a more intelligent solution.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: The hardest part I have is declaring var.
because it does not work with Javascript 'var groups.[0];'
I need help on this.

Comment: @Natetakeout: I don't know what you're trying to do with `var groups.[0];`.