# generate name of variables in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have some variables that their name ends with a number. now I need to change their values in a loop.
instead of putting all of the variables in the loop I was wondering if there is a way to generate the name of a variables in the loop? something like this maybe?

```
let bla1 = 0
let bla2 = 1
let bla3 = 2
...

for(var i = 0; i<somearray.lenght; i++){
  bla[i] += 1
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have seen something similar somewhere. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you have a bunch of variables with names ending in numbers they should be in an array like `bla = [0, 1, 2]` then access them with `bla[0]`. This will make *everything* easier.

Comment: **Take a look:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807231/how-to-dynamically-create-javascript-variables-from-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of an array:

```
let bla = [0, 1, 2];

for (let i = 0; i < bla.length; i++) {
  bla[i] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't generate variable names in a loop, but you can use object properties to achieve desired results:

```
const variables = {}

for(var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++){
  variables[`bla${i}`] = i
}

// later can be accessed like
console.log(variables.bla1)
```